# Random Generator Word Generator - PHP

Tags: php, random, generator

I'm trying to create a few random word generators on the same page which generates verbs, nouns etc. (creating eventually a plot generator but the user can select suggestions that randomly generate)

I've managed to create it, however, I want the random word generated to stay in the box when I click another generator on the same page (for example if I click suggest a noun and a word is generated, then I go to click suggest a Adjective and an adjective generates, but the noun disappears from the previous box)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

{
{

$Noun=array("just", "assume", "there", "are", "lots", "of", "nouns", "in", "here");

//echo rand(0, 2);
$myRandom = rand(0, 99);
//echo $Cars[$myRandom];
//if first name is blank/null then put 
}
?> 

<form action="quote.php">
    Noun<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" 
           value="<?php if (isset($_GET['Noun'])){echo $Noun[$myRandom];} }?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name ="Noun" value="Suggest">
</form>

<?php 

{
{

$Adj=array("just", "assume", "there", "are", "lots", "of", "adjectives", "in", "here");

//echo rand(0, 2);
$Random = rand(0, 99);
//echo $Cars[$myRandom];
//if first name is blank/null then put 
}
?> 

<form action="quote.php">
    Noun<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" 
           value="<?php if (isset($_GET['Adjective'])){echo $Adj[$Random];} }?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name ="Adjective" value="Suggest">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have a method in your form.  Are you planning on using `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I'm really new to this , I apologise. 

Basically I'm trying to re-create something similar on this website http://www.plot-generator.org.uk/story/ - the suggest buttons

I think maybe `POST` as I just want the code to appear inside the boxes - not to submit a new form??

Comment: Hey @Gareth, before i give an answer, i just want to know. Does quote.php redirect back to this page with some results?

Comment: Hi @Douglas - 

I've yes I think it does - I've probably done it wrong - I'm at the beginning of the process trying to build something similar to this website -

http://www.plot-generator.org.uk/story/ - 

At the moment I'm just trying to develop the suggest buttons before continuing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ajax instead of writing all the php and html code in one page which makes it unwieldy.

Set up an ajax call to a php script which will return a random name and then assign this name to the input box. For example;

Assign an id to your input and button;

```
<input id='name' name='name' />
<button id="submit">Generate random name</button>
```

In your ajax script, call the php script

```
$( "#submit" ).bind( "click", function() {
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
           url: "quote.php",
           success: function(result){
               //assign result to input
               $('#name').val(result);
           }
     })
  })
```

In your php script, generate the name in what ever way and send back the result by echo.

```
<?php

//generate random names and other stuff
echo $random;
```

You can modify it in any way you want.

Let me know if it helps or if you find a problem.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, however, is this not possible using just php? Just out of interest?

Comment: I don't think so. It might, but it would be better if did not have to keep on loading the page. Besides, you write a lot less code and it is structured better with jquery, ajax and php combined. Give it a try.

Comment: Appreciate it, I've tried it with the code above but it's going a little over my head and I cant manage to get it working - I've only started using PHP in the last 2 weeks and it's starting to make sense that for the page not to refresh you need a different language! Haven't used Ajax or these before. I'll keep trying it anyway, not sure what I'm doing wrong! 

Cheers man ,

Comment: Okay man. But ajax is simple if you have gone through javascript before. So you can take it slow with learning ajax and slowly make your way through php. If you have not tried javascript yet, try it out. It will make life a lot easier for you in the web design and development industry. All the best. ;).